# fail2ban with iptables-persistent

Tags: iptables, firewall, fail2ban, iptables-persistent

I've been running fail2ban for a bit, and recently installed `iptables-persistent` and am using it with `ipset` for a blacklist (there's one particular IP that is always hammering away at this machine).  The `ipset`/`iptables` persistency was a bit of work on Ubuntu, but that part seems to be working.  My issue is now the following:

When I reboot the machine, my (relevant portion) iptables looks like this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 682 packets, 84744 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  347 23254 f2b-sshd   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set blacklist src
  347 23254 f2b-sshd   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22

Chain f2b-sshd (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  694 46508 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

With this, I noticed also that `netfilter-persistent.service` was marked as `"loaded failed failed"` by `systemctl` even though it clearly loaded the rules files.  I tried editing my fail2ban service to load AFTER netfilter-persistent, and now netfilter-persistent is marked as `"loaded active exited"`...but the rules are still duplicated (apparently f2b creates the rules regardless of whether they already exist)

Manually editing this file each time I run `iptables-save` to delete the f2b entries is probably an acceptable option (particularly given that the consequences aren't all the grave if I forget to do so), but I'm wondering if there's a better option?

Answer (score 0):

One solution has already occurred to me, but it's...a little hackish imo.  Create the following file and run it.  It relies on the f2b entries--and no others--all having "f2b" in them, and this script being run rather than `iptables-save` directly...

```
~/bin£ cat saveFilteredIptables.sh
#!/usr/bin/zsh
sudo iptables-save | perl -ne 'print if !/f2b/'
~/bin£
```